# 12.04 scanner works fine as super-user but is not recognised as a normal user

Tags: users, scanner

I have an all-in-one printer Epson SX130, wich I have just tried to install. I got the printer working with no problem, but I couldn't set the scanner up. I have had another all-in-one printer before (Brother DCP-125C), and had just the same problem, so I decided to try the same trick I used to do then, running the scanning program as super-user:

```
$sudo simple-scan
```

and

```
$ sudo xsane
```

Once again, it worked just fine, and I could use the scanner.

Anyhow, this solution is a little annoying, because I also have to change the permissions to the files I get scanning like this.

I have been searching the internet for solutions and got to know this must have something to do with user groups permissions, but couldn't find a satisfying solution. Is there anyone with an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a member of the 'scanner' group. In a terminal, type `sudo adduser <yourusernamehere> scanner`. Replace `<yourusernamehere>` with your username, without the angle brackets.