# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot scan with Canon Pixma

Tags: 22.04, scanner

I have a Canon Pixma printer/scanner; upon first USB connection to my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, I did not need to do anything special to print.

However, when I tried to scan, `xsane` says "no devices available"; and:

```
$ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

And `simple-scan` (Document Scanner) writes: "Additional Software Needed" "You need to install driver software for your scanner", where "install driver software" notes: "You appear to have a Canon scanner, which is supported by the [Pixma SANE backend](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html). Please check if your scanner is supported by SANE ..."

However, I do have:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 256344 Mar 27  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1.1.1
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out while running:

```
$ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

...
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not open USB device 0x04a9/0x180b at 001:062: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
...
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.
...
  # You may want to **run this program as root** to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

Ah, if I need to run as root, `sudo` it is then:

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x180b [MG3000 series]) at libusb:001:062
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
...
```

Got it:

```
$ sudo scanimage -L
Created directory: /var/lib/snmp/cert_indexes
device `pixma:04A9180B_62FF57' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MG3000 Series multi-function peripheral
```

... and now also `sudo simple-scan` works, and so does `sudo xsane` although I do get a big fat warning against running `xsane` under `sudo` ...

So I tried, via

- [12.04 scanner works fine as super-user but is not recognised as a normal user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211447/12-04-scanner-works-fine-as-super-user-but-is-not-recognised-as-a-normal-user)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184367/scanimage-does-not-find-scanner-unless-sudoed-but-shows-up-with-sane-find-scan

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules  # file existed for me, so does /lib/udev/rules.d/99-libsane1.rules
```

added

```
# Canon Pixma
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

... near `LABEL="libsane_rules_end"`, did

```
sudo adduser myusername lp
sudo adduser myusername scanner
```

... and changed

```
$ cat /etc/sane.d/canon.conf
#canon.conf
scsi CANON IX
usb 0x04a9 0x180b
```

and

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

... and still I cannot get to use it without sudo.

Oh, well - this is what I was missing: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654731/scanner-available-only-with-sudo

> Next time you login, your uid will be able to use the scanner.

So after all that, you **HAVE TO** **LOG OUT** and then **LOG IN AGAIN** and **ONLY THEN** will `scanimage -L` work without `sudo`

Fuck coumputers, fuck scanners, fuck Canon, fuck Ubuntu, fuck Windows, fuck Mac OSX - what a shitty waste of time this is, just sheer entropy and shit ... I hate this so much; thus fucking world should just be destroyed to shit - hopefully all those shitty AIs being developed right now will send off all the nukes soon and put an end to this shitty existencde